# Getting error while uploading image using Retrofit2.0

Tags: android, retrofit, image-uploading, retrofit2

I am uploading an image file to server which throws the error with success response(200).

The error message I'm getting is:
Invalid file type! Only the following filetypes are allowed: bmp, csv, doc, docx, eps, flv, gif, jpeg, jpg, mkv, mov, mp3, mp4, mpeg, mpg, ogg, pdf, png, psd, rar, swf, txt, wav, wma, wmv, xls, xlsx, zip

Here is my code snippet:

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName));

Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
if (imageUri != null) {
    File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());
    RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + file.getName(), fileBody);
}

Call<UploadResponse> call = FotomateClient.getFotomateAPI().upload(authorization, map);
call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<UploadResponse> response) {
        if (response != null)
            if (response.body() != null)
                if (response.body().getCode() != null)
                    System.out.println(response.body().getCode());
        pd.dismiss();
        if (response.body().isSuccess()) {
            postCart("Bearer " + fm.getAccessToken(), response.body().getCode(), qty);
            dbHelper.deleteImage(id);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
}
```

I'm strucked at this point. Can any one help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the file format of  image file which you are uploading? Check if it is among allowed filetypes.

Comment: jpg and png @RohitSharma

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + file.getName(), fileBody);
```

Try this code

```
RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), file);
map.put("files\"; filename=\"image.png\"", fileBody);
```

And interface should look like:

```
@Multipart
@POST("mysite/upload")
Call<JsonElement> upload(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
```

Note: this code works and tested on retrofit 2.0.0-beta3

Comment: Thank you for answering but this is also not working @penguin